# Double summation with log in R

Tags: r

Please, anyone can help me to solve this R problem? I need to perform a double  summation with a log operator and I can’t find a way to do that. This summation is part of a log-likelihood expression of a probability distribution. I know this is at first a simple question, but I’m spending time on it without solution. Thanks in advance.

The summation formula is:

[image: \sum_{i=2}^{k} \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} n_i log(a + bi+pj)]

This, I think is a chunk of R code to prepare data to sum().

```
set.seed(123)
y <- rpois(100, 5)
a <- 5; b <- 1; p = 0.1
# ni <- frequency of repetitions from 100 Poisson distributed numbers
ni <- table(y);ni
i <- 2:length(ni)
j <- 1:(length(i)-1)
#Sum <- sum(????)
```

Comment: `s <- 0;
for (i in 2:length(ni)) {
    for (j in 1:(i-1)) {
        s <- s + ni[i] * log(a + b*i + p*j)
    }
};
s`

Comment: Thank you very much @MichalMajka.

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(123)
y <- rpois(100, 5)
a <- 5; b <- 1; p = 0.1
n <- as.vector(table(y))


result_list <- sapply(2:length(ni), function(i) {
    sapply(1:(i-1), function(j) {
        n[i]*log(a + b*i+p*j)
    })
})

result <- sum(unlist(result_list))
```

How about this?

Comment: Thank you a lot @thc.
By looking to your solution I found what was wrong in my looping code
*for(i in i){
    for(j in j){
      l[paste(i,j, sep = "")] <- ni[i]*log(a + b*i + p*j)
    }
  }*